# SignalR - OWIN - Multiple endpoints

Tags: signalr, owin, startup

I have a scenario as such.

A base class which modules are derived from.
Each module has it's own signalr hubs.
I want to host all modules in a single host, separated by module name.
Some modules will share hub names.

```
namespace domain.com.base
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string ApplicationName;
    }
}

namespace domain.com.billing
{
    public class Billing : BaseClass
    {
        ApplicationName = "Billing";
    }
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public void Credit(decimal amount)
        {
            Clients.All.Notify(amount);
        }
    }
}

namespace domain.com.reporting
{
    public class Reporting : BaseClass
    {
        ApplicationName = "Reporting";
    }
    public class ReportingHub : Hub
    {
        public Report GetReport(int Id)
        {
             return ReportModule.RetrieveReport(Id);
        }
    }
}
```

In OWIN.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder) is it possible to do something like such

```
namespace domain.com.external_access
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var asmList = GlobalResolver.Applications();
        foreach(var asm in asmList)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(asm.ApplicationName,false);
        }
    }
}
```

Effectively giving you something like so...

> http://domain.com.external_access/Reporting/hubs
>   http://domain.com.external_access/Billing/hubs

Comment: Have you tried: `app.MapSignalR("/Reporting/signalr"); app.MapSignalR("/Billing/signalr");...` ?

Comment: That would be great, however, would it not resolve the same hubs at both endpoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually this is doable, even if it requires some heavy working-around SignalR's tight coupling around `GlobalHost`.

---

<strike>*The answer below is based on what I remember, I don't have access to my code right now. I'll update the answer asap if errors are in there.*</strike>

Edit: I had it right yesterday evening. Just do as written below

---

You'll need to implement your own `IHubDescriptorProvider` and `IHubActivator` in order to have control over which `Hub` are found for each of your "endpoints". Furthermore you need to provide each endpoint with their own instance of `HubConfiguration` (which inherits from `ConnectionConfiguration`) that doesn't use the global host dependency resolver. Here's what this could look like:

```
class CustomSignalRConnectionConfiguration : HubConfiguration
{
    public CustomSignalRConnectionConfiguration() 
    {
        this.Resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();

        // configure your DI here...
        var diContainer = new YourFavouriteDi();

        // replace IHubActivator
        this.Resolver.Register(
            typeof(IHubActivator), 
            () => diContainer.Resolve<IHubActivator>());

        // replace  IHubDescriptorProvider
        this.Resolver.Register(
            typeof(IHubDescriptorProvider), 
            () => diContainer.Resolve<IHubDescriptorProvider>());

    }
}
```

For your single endpoints you could then do something like:

```
app.Map("/endpointName", mappedApp => 
{   
    var config = new CustomSignalRConnectionConfiguration();
    mappedApp.MapSignalR(config);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely try implement this. And let you know!